# Split string variable in Stata

Tags: split, stata, panel-data

I have a database with unique id for reports related with companies information. I have a variable which contains the companies involved in the report. For example, for ID 1, I have in the column companies “Compay A”, for ID 2 I have this column “Company A; Company B, Company C”.

I would like to split the variable companies and generate as many rows as companies involved in unique reports. So, I would like to have for the ID 2 three different rows, one for each, keeping the rest of variables equal. In other words, I would like to have a Panel Data, the ID is the company an the j variable the report (could be the same for some companies).

thanks in advance.

Comment: Cross-posted and answered at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1703048-split-string-variable  Please tell us about cross-posting.

Answer (score 1):

It is always helpful to provide some example data using `dataex`. I have done so in the solution to your question below. After you load the example data, run one line at the time to see what is happning.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str3 id str12 companies
"id1" "C-A;C-B;C-C;"
"id2" "C-X;C-Y;C-Z;"
end

* Split the string into one var per company
split companies , parse(";") generate(comp)

* Reshape from wide to long
reshape long comp, i(id)

* Clean up variables
drop _j companies
```